# Fluid sim silently fails at high resolution

Tags: fluid-simulation

When I push the resolution of my fluid sim to say 300 or more it will run for a while - about an hour then just quit, no errors. The remaining frames are not simulated and the domain turns back to a solid cube in those frames. At lower res it works fine. It does the same in blender 2.79 and 2.80. Not sure whats going on...

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you ran out of memory. The fluid sim is a notorious memory hog, and most users do something to "fake" more detail in fluids. Bit of a bummer because it takes a very beefy system to make liquid that doesn't look chunky and gross.

I think there's a project to improve this somewhere...

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have a beefy system 16gig of ram + 8 of swap so I don't think so. However ill dump memory usage to a log file all night and see if that's indeed happening. At the start of the sim however I have 10gig free.

Comment: No that's truly ram. These are exponential.